# Weird conformal map problem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

Construct a conformal map from the region $\omega$ = open disk of radius 1 centered at 0 minus the closed disk of radius 0.5 centered at 0.5 to $\mathbb{D}$ = disk radius 1 centered at 0.

I really have no clue where to begin.  I am alright at standard conformal map examples, but this one is hard.  Some help would be awesome.

Comment: What happens if you map the point where the two bounding circles touch to $\infty$ with a Möbius transformation?

Comment: What Daniel said. Guiding philosophy for many conformal map problems: circles are lines.

Answer (score 0):

(The deleted answer seemed basically fine, but, now that it's deleted, maybe there is reason to add something...) As in the comments, it is reasonable to think of lines-and-circles together, so the crescent-shaped region is a "generalized polygon" with just two (curvy) sides. It is not a *generic* bi-gon, because the two vertices are the same point. If the two vertices had been distinct, mapping one to $0$ and the other to $\infty$ by a linear fractional transformation, and then applying a suitable power map $z\to z^r$, converts any such to a half-plane, and then a disk by a Cayley transform. In contrast, in your special case, mapping the single vertex to $\infty$ by a linear fractional transformation gives you a *strip* (bounded by two parallel lines, thus intersecting just at $\infty$).

(As in the deleted answer), a suitable exponentiation maps a (bounded, open) strip to a half-plane, and then by Cayley to an open disk.